# Uniformly continuous on a compact set, still uniform on a subset?

Tags: analysis, continuity, compactness

So if I have a function that is uniformly continuous on a compact set K, do all subsets of K inherit the uniform continuity? If I restrict myself to the reals, this seems to be true. But what happens if I take an open subset of some general compact space K? I'm only guaranteed that closed subsets of K are still compact (and hence functions on it are uniformly continuous), with open subsets I don't 100% know (although it seems to be true in this specific case). I might be overthinking this (if so, please say so)

Comment: The restriction of a uniformly continuous function to a subspace is again uniformly continuous. The same $\delta$ works for $\epsilon$ in the subspace.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is true. Continuity and uniform continuity are inherited to all the subsets.

Comment: Great, it does make sense if I just use an analogy with continuity! I would upvote you if I could but please know I am appreciative of both you and Daniel Fischer's simple answers.